# Display NULL if some value is not found in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a sample data here

```
id  name
----------
1   Test1
2   Test2
3   Test3
4   Test4
```

So when I execute this QUERY

```
select id,name from table1 where name IN ('Test1','Test3','Test5')
```

It gives me an output of

```
id  name
----------
1   Test1
3   Test3
```

Is there any way I can get ouput like this

```
id     name
----------
1      Test1
3      Test3
null   Test5
```

Comment: yes, just emulate a table with the in values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [table value constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)(>= 2008):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM   table1 t
                     WHERE  E.Name = t.Name) 
           THEN E.Id
           ELSE NULL END AS Id,
       Name
FROM   (VALUES(1,'Test1'),(3,'Test3'),(5,'Test5')) E(Id,Name)
```

Comment: That's a neat way of doing it, every day is a school day

Comment: table value constructors were awesome addition.  But simpler than this is just to do an outer join to the constructed table. (and you don't really need `id` in the constructed table)

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but a CTE will do it

```
with MyData as
(
    select 'Test1' as MyName
    union
    select 'Test3' as MyName
    union
    select 'Test5' as MyName
)
select MyData.MyName, T1.id
from MyData
left join Table1 T1
on T1.Name = MyData.MyName
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure use a Values table constructor with an outer join:

```
Select o.id, m.name
   from (VALUES ('Test1'), ('Test3'), ('Test5')) t(name)
      left join myData o 
         on o.name = t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just left join a table of 'Test1','Test3','Test5' to the table in question

```
select id,t.name
from
(
    select 'Test1' as Name
    union
    select 'Test3' as Name
    union
    select 'Test5' as Name
) t
left join table1 on t.Name = table1.Name;
```

This will enumerate all matching ids or return null as id. You may wish to return only 3 rows then

```
select max(id) -- min(id)
    , t.name 
from
(
    select 'Test1' as Name
    union
    select 'Test3' as Name
    union
    select 'Test5' as Name
) t
left join table1 on t.Name = table1.Name
group by t.name;
```